# Is there a quotation mark symbol that doesn't float high above the baseline?

Tags: html, css, unicode

In inspecting my web page, I see that the quotation mark `"`, `'` or any other variant that I try finding such as `&ldquo;` or `&rdquo;` all, as you would expect, have a large white-space below them - it's normal for them to be floating above the baseline.

Is there any Unicode or HTML glyph that is *just* the quotation mark, not floating high above the line? I guess it's equivalent to asking, "Is there a quotation mark that is vertically centered within its box?" or "Is there a quotation mark that rests on the baseline?" which isn't very likely to exist. I've tried looking through [w3.org](https://w3.org) lists and places like CSS-Tricks, but no luck.

It's a problem because when using such a glyph in vertical Flexbox layouts, there's the illusion of a large space between it and the item below.

I've tried using `margin-bottom: -8px;` on the quote mark to negate this, but it isn't a flexible solution, especially once I mess around with line heights.

Link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ab6m5fvo/

Comment: Please post a JSFiddle or StackOverflow snippet that demonstrates this issue.

Comment: Added the fiddle. I'm trying to make a design for a block-quote. This will be the left edge of the block-quote, a big quotation symbol with a vertical line above and below, and the quote to the right, if that helps.

Comment: Maybe `«` and `»` (Double Angle Quotation Marks)? `\u00AB` and `\u00BB`

Comment: Can you expand more on when you'll be fiddling with a custom `line-height`? You could always set a fixed and known `line-height` just for the double-quote element which renders your concerns about `line-height` irrelevant.

Comment: @Dai I've been messing around with inline-code styling ```like what you see here```. Changing padding for inline code causes the background of the code to overlap with the background of inline-code above it, which I was trying to avoid by changing line-height. Plus, general readability improvements. Your point is something I will try, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer::** As of February 2021, the `lh` unit is not supported by any mainstream browsers. Eventually it will be - but for now my answer won't work).

> I've tried using `margin-bottom: -8px;` on the quote mark to negate this, but it isn't flexible solution, especially once I mess around with line heights.

[That's what the `lh` unit is for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Relative_length_units).

```css
.flexParent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100px;
}

.flexParent > .l {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

.flexParent > .q {
    margin-bottom: -0.4lh; /* NOTE: The value is `-0.4 * lh`, not `-0.41 * h` */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 2em;
}

.flexParent:hover > .q {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
  <div class="l"></div>
  <div class="q">"</div>
  <div class="l"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've deleted my remarks suggesting `ch` - I wasn't thinking when I wrote my answer. This answer is now only concerned with the (official, but currently unsupported) `lh` unit. I did think about suggesting `ex` as that's relative to glyph-height, but the OP wants an answer relative to `line-height`, and only the `lh` unit does that.

Comment: ```ch``` worked a charm, and there's no problem as of yet

Answer (score 1):

Various Unicode low quotation marks:

```
‚ U+201A SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
„ U+201E DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
❟ U+275F HEAVY LOW SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
❠ U+2760 HEAVY LOW DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
⹂ U+2E42 DOUBLE LOW-REVERSED-9 QUOTATION MARK
〟U+301F LOW DOUBLE PRIME QUOTATION MARK
 U+1F678 SANS-SERIF HEAVY LOW DOUBLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT
```

Comment: This is great, do you have similar characters which rest in the middle of their box?

Comment: @Harith I didn’t see anything like that. I searched all names with QUOT in the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regular quotation marks and a custom web font that displays quotation marks vertically centered.

If you are already using a web font, tweak it so that one of the many Unicode quotation mark characters is displayed in the middle of the line.

Or just use an image or an html `<svg>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You just need the `&bdquo;` special HTML character.